# Where is sculpt paint data stored (Blender 3.2)

Tags: python, sculpting, vertex-paint

When the new sculpt paint brush (new ver 3.2) is used to paint on the object, where is the paint data saved? How can it be accessed from python code?

Answer (score 2):

The paint brush writes to color attributes of the mesh. You can access it like so:

```py
import bpy

mesh = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data
color_data = mesh.color_attributes['Color'].data

# Color data is a per-vertex array, these two have the same size
print("Vertices: ", len(mesh.vertices))
print("Colors: ", len(color_data))

print(color_data[100].color[:])
color_data[200].color = (0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 1)
```

There seems to be experimental support in the latest alpha for texture-based painting but not in 3.2.